# How orientation is used in FAST features in ORB?

Tags: computer-vision, feature-extraction, sift, feature-detection

I was going throught [ORB paper](https://www.gwylab.com/download/ORB_2012.pdf). It states that it adds an efficiently computed orientation to FAST features. The description explains how it calculates

- Moment of patch $$m_{pq}=\sum_{x,y}x^py^pI(x,y)$$
- centroid $$C=\left(\frac{M_{10}}{M_{00}}\frac{M_{01}}{M_{00}}\right)$$ and
- orientation $$\theta=atan2(m_{01},m_{10})$$

It states that it uses $\theta$ to obtain steered version of BRIEF descriptor by first calculating $$S_\theta = R_\theta.S$$. However what I dont found is where does it use $θ$ in FAST features. Am I missing anything in the paper?